# ubuntu 14.04 strange things happening

Tags: unity

so I have some kind of problem with my ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. file mannager keeps crashing and some of the apps has a different layout for example system monitor looks weird:

[image]

file explorer does the same thing occasionally, what is happening and how to resolve it?

here is another img:

[image]

Comment: What desktop environment is this?

Comment: its Unity + numix theme + some kind of transparency bug

Comment: What have you done to Unity? Also, the file manager is called Nautilus, assuming you are using the default.

Comment: yes, it's nautilus here, didn't change anything, the only thing I did changed the theme to numix, oh I've installed corebird using these:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/corebird

till then it worked fine

Comment: Have you tried disabling that theme?

Comment: yes, I did that now, changed to Radiance / Ambiance, but the same problem remains

Comment: Maybe installing corebird modified some patched Gnome3 package. Try ppa-purging to remove corebird and see if this solves the issue.

Comment: strange... but re-installing fgrlx fixed the issue, I've used latest drivers from amd website, now I've installed ones from ubuntu drivers app and it works fine so far!

Answer (score 0):

The transparent window is as a result of Gnome PPA, remove it from **Software and Updates** and run `sudo apt-get update` then log-off and login again.

if you like to know with more thorough answer, go [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/547892/294611)